# Extracting specific node at index and ignore the others using a parameter to specify the index

Tags: xslt, indexing, parameters, xslt-2.0

I would like to be able to extract the nth node only of a set of nodes.

Given the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<problem>
    <header>This is a header</header>
    <lines>
        <line>This is the first line</line>
        <line>This is the second line</line>
        <line>This is the third line</line>
    </lines>
</problem>
```

How could I pass only the second line out, along with all other elements? In other words, I would like this to be output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<problem>
    <header>This is a header</header>
    <lines>
        <line>This is the second line</line>    
    </lines>
</problem>
```

I have a stylesheet that does what I want, but only if I hard code the index. This:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="index"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates  select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/problem/lines/line"/>

<xsl:template match="/problem/lines/line[2]">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces exactly what I want, but if I try to parameterize the index by replacing the [2] with parameter $index:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="index"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates  select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/problem/lines/line"/>

<xsl:template match="/problem/lines/line[$index]">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and set the value of $index to 2, I get this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<problem>
    <header>This is a header</header>
    <lines>
        <line>This is the first line</line>
        <line>This is the second line</line>
        <line>This is the third line</line>
    </lines>
</problem>
```

So I think that the template with the index match is not being found using a parameter.

How could I fix this so that a parameter can be used for the index?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working; I needed to convert the parameter from string to integer. This worked:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="index"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates  select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/problem/lines/line"/>

<xsl:template match="/problem/lines/line[number($index)]">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```